# i am not able to see my dbs after connecting to Altas

Tags: javascript, mongodb

[this this my mongosh after connecting to mongo Altas][1]

noTpewpew@DESKTOP-0LBRB59 MINGW64 ~/Desktop
$ mongosh --version
1.5.4

noTpewpew@DESKTOP-0LBRB59 MINGW64 ~/Desktop
$ mongosh "mongodb+srv://cluster0.4vcvkz0.mongodb.net/myFirstDatabase" --apiVersion 1 --username bishal-admin
Enter password: *******
Current Mongosh Log ID: 630dcd25fc1e7464dc7ccfb7
Connecting to:          mongodb+srv://@cluster0.4vcvkz0.mongodb.net/myFirstDatabase?appName=mongosh+1.5.4
Using MongoDB:          5.0.11 (API Version 1)
Using Mongosh:          1.5.4

For mongosh info see: https://docs.mongodb.com/mongodb-shell/

Warning: Found ~/.mongorc.js, but not ~/.mongoshrc.js. ~/.mongorc.js will not be loaded.
You may want to copy or rename ~/.mongorc.js to ~/.mongoshrc.js.
Atlas atlas-ssuf8v-shard-0 [primary] myFirstDatabase> show dbs

Atlas atlas-ssuf8v-shard-0 [primary] myFirstDatabase> show dbs

Atlas atlas-ssuf8v-shard-0 [primary] myFirstDatabase> show DBS
MongoshInvalidInputError: [COMMON-10001] 'DBS' is not a valid argument for "show".
Atlas atlas-ssuf8v-shard-0 [primary] myFirstDatabase> show dbs

Atlas atlas-ssuf8v-shard-0 [primary] myFirstDatabase> show collections
MongoServerError: user is not allowed to do action [listCollections] on [myFirstDatabase.]
Atlas atlas-ssuf8v-shard-0 [primary] myFirstDatabase> show dbs

Atlas atlas-ssuf8v-shard-0 [primary] myFirstDatabase>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the important error:

`MongoServerError: user is not allowed to do action [listCollections] on [myFirstDatabase.]`

Look into [roles](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/manage-users-and-roles/) and [privilege actions](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/privilege-actions).